# Approximating real number as logarithm of naturals

Tags: logarithms, approximation, integers

I want to approximate a real number $r$ as a logarithm using integer numbers:
\begin{equation}
r\approx\log_a K \;(a,K \in \Bbb N,\; r\in \Bbb R)
\end{equation}
Intuitively, the larger $a$ and $K$ are allowed to be, the better the approximation.

Of course, I could seach numerically the best approximation (e.g. with a computer program), but I imagine there must be an algorithm to directly find a list of progressively better approximations. For example, if instead of a logarithm I were using a fraction $r=a/K$, I could use the method of continued fractions.

Example: for $r=1.3807$, with a program I found $r \approx \log_5 9,\;\log_{6} 12,\;\log_9{21},\;\log_{10}24,\;\dots$

How do I find the next pair $(a,K)$?

Comment: How about _Taylor series_ ?

Comment: I am not sure how they could be applied in this case, can you provide a sketch of your idea?